# TypeError: b is undefined when appending

Tags: javascript, html

I know I have issue in referring value to `this` after seeing some similar questions on this site, but not able to solve this in my context.
any one could help me to solve this , how do I refer value of `splitInput` to `this` as when I replace `this` with `splitInput` it is giving errors as splitInput is not an function
here is my code snippet of only js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function styleBox(){
        var userInput= document.getElementById('invite-emails').value;
        var splitInput=userInput.split(",");

        for(var i=0; i< splitInput.length; i++) {
            $(this).append("<span style='background-color:red'>"+splitInput[i]+((i< splitInput.length-1) ? ",":"")+"</span>");
        }
    };

    $(function(){
        $(".team-btn").click(function(e) {
            $('.team-intro').replaceWith($(".team-invite").show());
        });
    });
    $("#invite-emails").keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 32) { 
            styleBox();
        }
    });
```

Comment: What does the title have to do with your question? Please properly indent your code and post a [mcve]

Comment: I'm getting that error in browser console when I run this code

Comment: The code you posted has no `b` variable

Comment: @j08691 Usually jQuery minified throws such errors

Comment: @Justinas Possibly. I'd still like the OP to post a [mcve]

Comment: @Prasad_Joshi Are you trying to color text inside input?

Answer (score 1):

You call `styleBox` without setting `this` reference, you need to do [`styleBox.apply(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
$("#invite-emails").keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 32) { 
        styleBox.apply(this);
    }
});
```

Than inside `styleBox` `this` will be showing to `#invite-emails`

Comment: hey it is still not working as expected it is not applying css property as background-color: red, though error is gone now